# R DataTable Select Rows

Tags: r, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("Student"=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
"Grade"=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
"Score"=c(5, 7, 9, 2, 2, 3, 10, NA, 3))


data2=data.frame("Student"=c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3),
"Grade"=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
"Score"=c(5, 7, 9, 10, NA, 3))
```

I have 'data1' and wish for 'data2' where I ONLY include 'Student' if 'Score' at 'Grade' = 1 is at least 4.

My only knowledge of how to do this is doing it by 'Grade' and 'Score' but that does not give desired output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
data1=data1[Grade==1 & Score >=4)
```

## how is it possible to specify that I wish to select all STUDENTS who have a Score>=4 at Grade 1 and not just the ROWS

Comment: Could do `setDT(data1)[, if(Score[Grade == 1] >= 4) .SD, by = Student]` or more cumbersome `setDT(data1)[data1[Grade == 1 & Score >= 4], .SD, on = .(Student)]`

Comment: @David Arenburg thank you so much it works in toy example but in real data ': argument is of length zero'

Comment: It's probably because you have students that don't have `Grade == 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do a join with your desired conditions to retain the `Student` id.

Does this work?

```r
library(data.table)
data1 <- data.frame("Student"=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                    "Grade"=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                    "Score"=c(5, 7, 9, 2, 2, 3, 10, NA, 3))
data2 <- data.frame("Student"=c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3),
                    "Grade"=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                    "Score"=c(5, 7, 9, 10, NA, 3))
setDT(data1)
setDT(data2)

wanted <- data1[ Grade == 1 & Score >= 4, .( Student ) ]

setkey( wanted, Student )
setkey( data1, Student )

data3 = data1[ wanted ]

data2
#>    Student Grade Score
#> 1:       1     1     5
#> 2:       1     2     7
#> 3:       1     3     9
#> 4:       3     1    10
#> 5:       3     2    NA
#> 6:       3     3     3
data3
#>    Student Grade Score
#> 1:       1     1     5
#> 2:       1     2     7
#> 3:       1     3     9
#> 4:       3     1    10
#> 5:       3     2    NA
#> 6:       3     3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>